# Any Example that Prove Initializer List Call before Constructor C++

Tags: c++, constructor

I have searched but still didn't get easy and proper answer, Below is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Parent
{
    private:
        int a;

    public:
        Parent():a(3) { cout << a; }
};

int main()
{
    Parent obj; 
    return 0;
}
```

Can you add additional lines of code that can prove or show me that initializer list call before constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would modify you code ever so slightly:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Parent
{
    public:
        int a;
    public:
        Parent():a(3){
            a = 4;
        }

};

int main()
{
    Parent obj;
    cout << obj.a;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is `4`, thus `a` was initialized with `3` and then assigned `4`.

Comment: Great and Easy..!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply add data member, which has constructor, which prints something. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Data {
    Data(int a) { 
        cout << "Data constructor with a=" << a << endl;
    }
};

class Parent
{
    private:
        Data a;
    public:
        Parent():a(3){
            cout << "Parent constructor" << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
   Parent obj;
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Data constructor with a=3
Parent constructor
```

Conclusion: `Data` constructor was called before constructor body of `Parent`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get variable "a" value 10 in this program , a assigned before constructor method called .

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Test
{
    public:
        int a,b;
    public:
        Test():a(b){
            b=10;
        }
};

int main()
{
   Test obj;
   cout<<"a :"<<obj.a<<" b:"<<obj.b;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is best shown with multiple classes:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
        A()
        {
             std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
        }
};

class B
{
    private:
        A* a;

    public:
        // Call a's constructor
        B():a(new A)
        {
             // Some code
        }

        ~B()
        {
            delete a;
        }
};

int main()
{
    B obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I use pointers here to show that `B::a` is being initialised as `B` is. It is equally valid to have no pointers, but I think this helps to visualise what is going on